# Why aren't tiles appearing pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a tile map that makes all `1`'s a tile and the whole outer layer is `1`'s. However, when I run my code, the tiles only appear at the top of the screen. Shouldn't they appear around the entire map since I have `1`'s all around?

```
    # import modules
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#init
pygame.init()

#screen creation
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 1000
tile_size = 50

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Crashlandingv6')

#load images
bg_img = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
bg_img = pygame.transform.scale(bg_img, (1000,1000))
rect = bg_img.get_rect()



class World():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.tile_list = []

        #load images
        dirt_img = pygame.image.load('dirt.png')
        for row in data:
            row_count = 0
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size,tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img,img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1
    def draw(self):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0],tile[1])


world_data  = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

world = World(world_data)
#main loop
run = True
while run:


    screen.blit(bg_img,rect)
    world.draw()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `row_count = 0` You should move that to before `for row in data:`

Comment: See also: [enumerate](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets focus on this part of your code:

```
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.tile_list = []

        #load images
        dirt_img = pygame.image.load('dirt.png')
        for row in data:
            row_count = 0
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size,tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1
```

As you can see, you have a nested `for`-loop; during each iteration of the outer `for` loop, you set the values of both `row_count` and `col_count` to `0`.

So, the `row_count` will always remain zero when it gets called in the inner `for`-loop no matter how many times you increment it by `1` at the end of each iteration of the outer `for`-loop, because it just gets set back to `0` at the beginning of each iteration of the outer `for`-loop.

Simply move the `row_count = 0` out and above the outer `for`-loop:

```
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.tile_list = []

        #load images
        dirt_img = pygame.image.load('dirt.png')
        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size,tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1
```

Comment: why does that happen for row count  and not col count?

Comment: @JacksonCadeau Because the `col_count` value is supposed to be set beck to `0` at the start of each row :)